# Do I need to use buffer.rewind() if I'm using buffer.get() in a IF conditional statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, int, conditional-statements, buffer

Example. Does the position of the buffer move after checking this condition?

`if (variable==buffer.get()) {
    do something;
    buffer.rewind()
}`

Comment: You need to provide much more information. What is the buffer, what are you checking. This is an incomplete question. Please update with the appropriate details so it can be answered.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it is an intbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referring to a [`IntBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html), then: ***Yes***.

The javadoc of [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get--) says:

> Reads the int at this buffer's current position, and then **increments the position**.

So if the `if` statement is false, then the buffer definitely moved.

If the `if` statement is true, then [`rewind()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind--) is called, and javadoc says:

> The position is **set to zero** and the mark is discarded.

So if the position wasn't initially zero before the `if` statement, then the buffer moved back to zero.

*To recap:* If the buffer position is initially at beginning, and the `if` statement is true, then that code will leave the buffer at same position, otherwise the buffer will be "moved".

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: I'll delete the question soon as I know its quite poor, but I got the answer I was after.